# How to write to a file multiple times in java?

Tags: java, file, overwrite

I am working on a program that is going to calculate alla prime numbers between 2 and 10 000 and write this to a file.

People tell different ways on how to write to a file so I took one sugestion and tried it. 
At first i put my file creation in a loop with ended in the program recreating the file each time, then I took the file creation out of the loop and now I get errors.

Could someone tell me if this is the way to do it, if not, how should it be done, or how can i make this work?

To already have a file could also work and then just add/edit/overwrite it from my program.

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    int prime = 2;

    File file = new File("out.txt");      // how should i do this part
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);     

    while(prime < 10000){
        boolean isPrime = true;

        for( int i = 2; i <= sqrt(prime); i++){
            if( (prime%i) == 0 ){
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime){
            bw.write(prime + " ");     // and this
        }
        prime++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Please post stack traces if available.

Comment: You may want to have a look [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62005822/11322237)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your errors are due to checked exceptions that some of your code can throw and that you are not catching or declaring `main` to throw. You are also potentially leaking resources. If you are using Java 7, I suggest the following (using a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)):

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    File file = new File("out.txt");
    try (
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
    ) {
        for (int prime = 2; prime < 10000; ++prime) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            final int limit = (int) sqrt(prime); // 
            for (int i = 2; i <= limit && isPrime; i++) {
                isPrime = prime % i != 0;
            }
            if (isPrime){
                bw.write(String.valueOf(prime));
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Prior to Java 7, you should do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    File file = new File("out.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        for (int prime = 2; prime < 10000; ++prime) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            int limit = (int) sqrt(prime);
            for( int i = 2; i <= limit && isPrime; i++) {
                isPrime = prime % i != 0;
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                bw.write(String.valueOf(prime));
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bw != null) {
            try { bw.close(); }
            catch (IOException ignored) { }
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside, your approach to testing primality is extremely inefficient. You might want to take a look at using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Thank you! Now it works as it should!
I am aware that this method is not the best but it is an easy way.
But i will look into your suggestion and maybe do another program with that method!

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine, just be sure to close your streams when you're done.

If you don't want to make a new file each time, you can open an existing file in write mode

[How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

You must write and then close the FileWriter and BufferedWriter at the end.

Put these lines at the last after the loop --

```
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

In addition using  `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);` would let you append to the existing file. Please, notice the 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

I would put `bw.write(prime + " ");` in a `try/catch` block to exit gracefully if something fails.  You might also want to inclue a `file.createNewFile()` statement if the file does not `file.exists()`.

Lastly, make sure you `bw.close()` the buffered writer.

Other than that, yep, everything looks up to par.

I would do a:

```
try {
  bw.write(stuff);
}
Catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I put the try/catch block in my if statement and the bw.close(); after my while loop but it still wont compile. It says: "unreported exception ioexception must be caught or declared to be thrown" over my file creation

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuffer to cache all the prime numbers and after the for loop completes iterating over all the numbers, convert the StringBuffer to a String and write to your output file in one go.